# how can i detect faces with android using opencv, from all positions of the camera?

Tags: android, c++, qt, opencv

I made an application to detect faces and draw a rectangle around the face. The problem is that it only detects faces in a position, that is, I can detect faces with the cell in a position, but when I turn it stops detecting.

I want to know if there is an algorithm that allows me to detect faces in any position, whether lying down, facing up, etc ...

I'm using the xml of frontalFace.xml.

```
    vector< Rect > detectedFaces;
    detectedFaces.clear();
    frontalFaceClassifier.detectMultiScale( dst, detectedFaces,
                                   1.5, 3, 2 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE , Size(90,90) );

    qDebug()<<"Cantidad de caras en el vector : " << detectedFaces.size();
    if( detectedFaces.size() > 0 ){
        actualFace = detectedFaces.at( 0 );

        countDetectedFaces++;
        qDebug()<<"**********qwerty**********"<<detectedFaces.size()<<"----------";
    }
    for(int i=0;i<detectedFaces.size();i++)
    {

         // Dibujar un cuadrado en la zona en donde se detecta la cara.
         Rect dibujarCuadrado = detectedFaces.at(i);
         cv::rectangle (mat, dibujarCuadrado, 20, 1, LINE_8, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's seems you don't have a very clear idea what you're doing. It's not about algorithm but about classification.

You need to train your classifier with the set of information you need.
OpenCV give you pre-trained sets such as "frontal faces" and "profile faces" in XML files, so first start running the svm with both frontal and profile, then do some filter to remove overlapping from results.

If you want to add other features to your recognizer you need to train it by yourself.